# Calendar Print Method

Tags: ruby, datetime, formatting

I'm currently learning Ruby and need help in editing code to be more idiomatic. I have the method below I could use some pointers on how to make more "Ruby" :-)

```
def print_cal(day_of_week, month_len)
  days = %w(Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun)
  days.each { |day| print "#{day} " }

  puts

  day_num = 1
  month_started = false
  while day_num <= month_len
    (1..7).each do |i|
      if  day_of_week > i && month_started == false
        print '    '
      else
        month_started = true
        print ' ' if day_num < 10
        print " #{day_num} " if day_num <= month_len
        day_num += 1
      end
    end
    puts
  end
end
```

Comment: Well done using the `%w( )`, nice indentation, I'm a little confused as to what you're trying to do with `print '    '`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I would rather return array of strings than the whole text -- this gives ability to loop over or even reverse lines
2. I would totally get rid of temp variables and their assignments
3. I would use even another approach to interpolate number into string: `"%3s" % date`

And some other tricks:

```
def format_calendar offset, month_length
  [*1..month_length].unshift(*Array.new(offset)).
    each_slice(7).map{ |week|
      week.map{ |date| "%3s" % date }.join " "
    }.unshift "Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun"
end

puts format_calendar 2, 31
```

Or if you find `unshift` ugly, try this, but it does pointless interpolation for weekday titles:

```
def format_calendar offset, month_length
  [
    * %w{Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun},
    * Array.new(offset),
    * (1..month_length),
  ].each_slice(7).map{ |week|
    week.map{ |date| "%3s" % date }.join " "
  }
end

puts format_calendar 2, 31
```

Comment: I like the second solution. I'm not entirely sure how the splat operator works in this case though. Do we need it on Array.new(offset)? Or is it just there for "symmetry". Could the same be done without a splat? Splats seem a bit cryptic to use in a language like ruby .

Comment: @LeoNet, without splat the array would be nested -- `[[a,b],[c,d],[e,f]]`, where `Array.new` is `[c,d]`. Instead of splat you could use concatenations but had to add `()` around all of it to apply the `.each_slice` method: `( %w{} + Array.new() + (1..).to_a ).each_slice`

Answer (score 11):

Here's my take, with explanations below:

```
def print_calendar(offset, month_length)
  puts "Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun"
  dates = [nil] * offset + (1..month_length).to_a
  dates.each_slice(7) do |week|
    puts week.map { |date| date.to_s.rjust(3) }.join(' ')
  end
end
```

1. I'd call the first parameter `offset` rather than `day_of_week`. For one, `day_of_week` would seem to imply that you can use a `Date` object's `wday` as the offset, but `wday`'s range is 0-6, with zero being Sunday, so that won't work. Also, with `day_of_week` I wonder if you mean a day's name, or its number? Oh, and which week are we talking about? The name `offset` is a lot more generic, but that might be a good thing here.
   I've also spelled out `print_calendar` and `month_length` entirely. While those names weren't too confusing, there's no reason to skip a few letters.
2. Also note that the offset behaves slightly different from yours: In your method, the minimum offset is 1. That makes sense if you think "start on the 1st day", but it makes less sense if you think "offset everything by 1". So here, the minimum offset is zero.
3. [`Array#join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-join) is a nice method to know when you have to print lists of stuff (in any language, not just Ruby).  You could have done `puts %w(Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun).join(' ')` instead of your first 3 lines. But the end result would be no different than simply printing a hard-coded string, so that's what we're doing here instead.
4. In Ruby, you rarely have to use `while` loops. Generally, it's easier to construct and manipulate arrays using the built-in methods in [`Array`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html) and those mixed-in by the [`Enumerable`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html) module. (Seriously, if you're learning Ruby, go read as much as you can from those two links; it's some the most useful stuff in Ruby, and you'll be using it a lot.)
   Here, we're constructing a `dates` array of `nil`s that's `offset` items long by using Ruby's nifty ability to [multiply an array by a number](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-2A). Then we use [`+` to concatenate](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-2B) that array with an array that's just the numbers 1..`month_length`.
   In other words, `dates` consists of zero or more "blanks" (the offset) followed by the date numbers of the month.
5. [`each_slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) should be fairly self-explanatory: Go through an array, X items at a time. In this case we go through it 7 items at a time (i.e. a week), which is what we need for each row/line of text.
6. Each of these `week`s are just arrays of `nil`s and/or numbers, so we convert each of them, using `map`, to an array of strings. Each blank/number is first converted to a string, and then padded with spaces using [`rjust`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-rjust). Finally, this mapped array is joined and output.

And that's it, really.

Calling `print_calendar(2, 31)` will print the following:

```
Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
          1   2   3   4   5
  6   7   8   9  10  11  12
 13  14  15  16  17  18  19
 20  21  22  23  24  25  26
 27  28  29  30  31
```

However, it'd be even more idiomatic to let the method simply return the text *without* printing it. That could be done like so:

```
def format_calendar(offset, month_length)
  lines = [ "Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun" ]
  dates = [nil] * offset + (1..month_length).to_a
  dates.each_slice(7) do |week|
    lines << week.map { |date| date.to_s.rjust(3) }.join(' ')
  end
  lines.join("\n")
end
```

After which you can do something like

```
puts format_calendar(2, 31)
```

to print it.

Edit: As [Naklion's answer rightly points out](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/64494/14370), it'd be even nicer to return an array of strings (the individual lines of text). In this case, you can do so by simply omitting the `.join("\n")` on the last line of the method above. That'll give you more structured data to work with, instead of a text blob.
As for printing, you don't need to change anything, since `puts` automatically adds linebreaks when printing an array.

Comment: I would even rather return array of strings, than the whole text. `puts` won't break, but you'll get more possibilities.

Comment: @Nakilon Good point. I'd forgotten that `puts` still does the right thing with that. I'll add a bit to my answer

Comment: Couldn't resist from other things, so I already posted it in mine.

Comment: @Nakilon Even better :) I'll still add a small note, and point people toward your answer (I'd actually written the edit 20 minutes ago - I just forgot to click "Save"... :P )

Comment: Thank you for your excellent explanations I have learned a lot!!!

Answer (score 3):

For more idiomatic Ruby,

- Use `puts` instead of `print` to output a newline.
- To make that happen, use `map` and `join`.
- Construct your weeks using `Enumerable#each_slice`.

In addition, you should use `sprintf` to ensure that each cell is formatted to the same width. That works for the headers, the blank padding, one-digit dates, and two-digit dates.

```
def print_cal(starting_day_of_week, month_len)
  days = %w(Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun)   
  leading_pad = [nil] * (starting_day_of_week - 1)
  dates = (1..month_len).to_a

  calendar = days + leading_pad + dates
  calendar.each_slice(7) do |week|
    puts week.map { |date| sprintf('%3s', date) }.join(' ')
  end
end
```